# EXCEPTION: Cannot set property 'variablename' of undefined

Tags: angular, get, ionic2

I am having a get request written inside my constructor like the below one

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public productServices:Products,
              public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

        this.productServices.getCartCount(function(data){
      console.log("checking getCartCount" +JSON.stringify(data));
      this.cartCount=data.count;
    })

    this.productServices.getWishlistCount(function(data){
      console.log("checking getWishlistCount" +JSON.stringify(data));
      this.wishlistCount = data.count;
      
    })

    console.log("invoking the ionviewload " +this.cartCount);

    console.log("invoking the ionviewload " +this.wishlistCount);
}
```

yes my `cartCount` and `wishlistCount` is updated successfully

the problem is my `constructor()` runs only once i need it to be do a get request when ever the view appears.

so here what i try to achieve this

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    console.log("invoking the Home page ionView did load ");
    
    this.productServices.getCartCount(function(data){
      console.log("checking getCartCount" +JSON.stringify(data));
      this.cartCount=data.count;
    })

    this.productServices.getWishlistCount(function(data){
      console.log("checking getWishlistCount" +JSON.stringify(data));
      this.wishlistCount = data.count;
      
    })

    console.log("invoking the ionviewload " +this.cartCount);

    console.log("invoking the ionviewload " +this.wishlistCount);
  }
```

but i am getting error as

> EXCEPTION: Cannot set property 'cartCount' of undefined
>
> Is there any other way to write a get request when ever my view appears.

UPDATE:
check my products.ts file

```
getCartCount(callbackFn: (productsArray: any) => void){
      this.restService.get('/getCartCount', (data)=>{
        console.log("invoking get CartCount details");
        callbackFn(data);
      }, () => {
        callbackFn([])
      })
    }

    getWishlistCount(callbackFn: (productsArray: any) => void){
      this.restService.get('/getWishlistCount', (data)=>{
        console.log("invoking get WishlistCount details");
        callbackFn(data);
      }, () => {
        callbackFn([])
      })
    }
```

and rest.ts file

```
get(url:string, successCallbackFn: (data: any)=>void, errorcallbackFn: ()=>void) {
      console.log("Calling " + this.configurator.restServerBaseUrl + url);
      var authdetails = ""
      if (this.tokenNeeded(url)) {
        authdetails += '&user_id=' + this.userId;
        authdetails += '&access_token=' + this.authToken;
        authdetails += "&"
      }
      this.http.get(this.configurator.restServerBaseUrl + authdetails + this.configurator.restServerControllerUrl + url).subscribe(
        result => successCallbackFn(result.json()),
        error => errorcallbackFn())
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share your `productServices` ?

Comment: @ranakrunal9 as you can see my constructor code that is working fine i am getting the value and every thing is working fine. but i want that get request to be run when ever my view is loaded

Comment: have you tried with `OnInit` ?

Comment: May I ask why you send a callback to the service instead of returning a promise/observable from the service in order to use then/subscribe to get the response?

Comment: @sebaferreras yes i am returning the promises(in services) and that promises is called in the pages(homePage.ts) . that's how my constructor works fine

Comment: @ranakrunal9 yes i tried but same error my console.log in my ionviewDidload is showing undefiend

Comment: @ranakrunal9 check my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest a small change in your services? Instead of sending callbacks (and making the code kind of hard to understand/maintain) you can just return the `get()` (which is an Observable)

**rest.ts**

```
public get(url:string) {
      console.log("Calling " + this.configurator.restServerBaseUrl + url);
      var authdetails = "";
      if (this.tokenNeeded(url)) {
        authdetails += '&user_id=' + this.userId;
        authdetails += '&access_token=' + this.authToken;
        authdetails += "&"
      }

      let fullUrl = this.configurator.restServerBaseUrl + authdetails + this.configurator.restServerControllerUrl + url;
      return this.http.get(fullUrl).map(res => res.json());
    }
```

**products.ts**

```
public getCartCount(){
      console.log("invoking get CartCount details");
      return this.restService.get('/getCartCount');
}

public getWishlistCount(){
      console.log("invoking get WishlistCount details");
      this.restService.get('/getWishlistCount');
}
```

And then in your component code, you just need to `subscribe` to the result, and you will get the response (already parsed):

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    console.log("invoking the Home page ionView did load ");

    this.productServices.getCartCount().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log("checking getCartCount" +JSON.stringify(data));
      this.cartCount=data.count;
    });

    this.productServices.getWishlistCount().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log("checking getWishlistCount" +JSON.stringify(data));
      this.wishlistCount = data.count;
    });

    console.log("invoking the ionviewload " +this.cartCount);

    console.log("invoking the ionviewload " +this.wishlistCount);
}
```

By doing things in this way, you can be sure that the `this` keyword points to the instance of the component.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i have almost completed my project how am gone a change the get requestion callback fun for only ionViewDidLoad()